# Difference between an information question and a distrusting question

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

What I'm looking for is a way to literally describe two different kinds of questions, first the information seeking question:

"*what is your name?*"
or
"*how old are you?*"

with the more distrusting and vague:

"*what are you doing?*"
or
"*are you sure about this?*"

Is there a another word for one of these two types of queries? To question someone can be both neutral (first kind) and negative (second kind).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't find snappy answers for these. I certainly can't think of any myself. As section headings, I'd probably use 'requesting information' (x2), 'asking for an explanation of someone's behaviour' and 'checking someone's confidence in a course of action they propose or a statement they have made'.

Comment: You've asked more "vague" and more "distrusting", probably twice as hard to find a word.

Comment: While I do not believe there are accepted terms for the divisions you are looking for.  One type  of question that has a name is a rhetorical question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question  .. which might be useful to work with for some of your second example .  While I do not think it is an accepted term I might consider "expository question" ... there is also a common term "direct question"  which would include your first two examples however an "indirect question" would also seek information.  So "direct question" is more about grammar than purpose (other issues too)

Comment: Maffelu, those examples won’t work, although the distinctions you’re looking to define seem fairly clear.

"what are you doing?" Is comparable with, not distinct from “what is your name?" or "how old are you?"

Didn’t you mean something like "what d’you think you’re doing?" or “what did you say you were doing?” And aren’t they still dodgy?

Why not take 100-odd examples - from, for instance, newspapers, books, radio or TV - and classify them according to your needs.

Who thinks if that succeeds, it’s not half-way to a doctoral thesis?

Comment: Hehe, I was hoping there'd be a term for it, there seems to be definition and terms for most odd little variations in most languages. I think I'll have to go with @Tom22 and accept that there is no answer, maybe direct/indirect is the closest I can get.

Comment: It's not quite a rhetorical question, which is a question that actually makes a statement, so no answer is really desired or expected (answering it suggests they didn't really get the point). Perhaps "accusatory question" is a good description. But I also don't think there's a common term for them.